# Too many redirects - cookies JS + php implementation

Tags: php, cookies

I have a simple website where you need only a password to access the contents. Then there are 3 fields where user inputs data, which are then stored in cookies. In the end - there is a logout script that resets the session and unsets cookies.

Please find the relevant code below:

Login page (index)

```
<?php
session_start();

$password = '';
$wrongPassword = '';
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
$password = $_POST['login_passcode'];
if ($password === 'PASSCODE') {
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    header('LOCATION:/personal.php');
    die();
} else {
    $wrongPassword = true;
}
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['m_username'])) {
header('LOCATION:/personal.php');
die();
}
?>
```

The page with contents, where user inputs name, department and start date

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header("Location:/index.php");
die();
}
?>
```

and the logout script:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])):
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 7000000,'/');
endif;
if (isset($_COOKIE['m_username'])):
    setcookie('marriott_username', '', time() - 7000000,'/');
endif;
if (isset($_COOKIE['m_startdate'])):
    setcookie('marriott_startdate', '', time() - 7000000,'/');
endif;
if (isset($_COOKIE['m_department'])):
    setcookie('m_department', '', time() - 7000000,'/');
endif;
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header ("Location:/index.php");
die();
?>
```

jQuery to create cookies below:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Cookies do expire (at least on chrome), however after trying to access website after a few hours or days, I get the error about too many redirections. I believe this might be due to some differences between session expiration time and cookies expiration time (5 days for cookies), but I don't really know where to start fixing these...

Also, on Internet Explorer (IE8) the redirects problem occurs even when I go through logout directly.

Will be grateful for any help,
E.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code much? specifically before the redirections? At least then you would know where the error is occuring! =]

Comment: This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441650/php-the-website-has-too-many-redirects-when-use-php-sessions-with-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in thinking different cookie expirations are behind the too many redirects problem.

If `isset($_COOKIE['m_username'])` is true in the index page, then you are redirected to the personal page, in which if `if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ''))` is also true, it sends you back to the index, therefore creating a loop. This would be caused by the session cookie expiring before the cookies you set.

The `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` superglobals refer to two different sets of cookies. One solution is to use just the PHP session and store all your session data in the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

For example:

```
$_SESSION['m_username'] = 'whatever_value';
```

This will however generate an overhead in extra memory usage. If you still want to use your own cookies then just make sure any logic determining redirects is based on the session, not the presence of cookies you set.

For example:

```
// When logging in
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

// On every page that requires login
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']) // Redirect
```

Comment: I think it doesn't go with what I was currently trying to achieve - I'll be grateful if you can prove me wrong :) I wanted to store these 3 variables in cookies for 5 days, so every time a user opens the website during this time, they don't go to the login page, but straight to the content page. I don't think it can be done this way though, cause session is closed once you close the browser.

Comment: You are correct. This page has an overview of the methods available for modifying the PHP session behaviour: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php. Checkout session_set_cookie_params, particularly the lifetime parameter.

Comment: Used session_set_cookie_params and everything works perfect! Cheers :)